# My bot doesn't load after using custom actions in Rasa

Tags: python, rasa, nlu

Whenever I am trying to use custom actions in Rasa by modifying my **actions.py** and adding custom actions in **domain.yml** it just breaks up my rasa shell.

Before changing my **actions.py** and adding action endpoint in **endpoints.yml**, I get something like this.
[image: See how I get this **BOT LOADED MESSAGE**]

But after I add my custom actions in actions.py and modify my endpoints.yml, rasa shell doesn't show this BOT LOADED Message anymore, instead it shows NLU loaded and it doesn't give the expected response.
[image: I don't get BOT LOADED MESSAGE ANYMORE]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show your code but copy paste it directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with your action server. Most likely, the latest model in your `models` directory is an nlu-only model because core training was skipped due to an invalid domain file.  Try retraining the model, and check that both NLU and Core trained correctly. If yes, check that the most recent model in your `models` folder contains both an `nlu` and a `core` subdirectory if you unzip it. Then run `rasa shell --model <path to your model>.tar.gz>` to be sure that the model you just checked on is the one being loaded.